# Invalid object name 'hibernate_unique_key

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have this error when i try to save my entity:
Invalid object name 'hibernate_unique_key

What is the problem?
With the SQL profiler i have this query:
select next_hi from hibernate_unique_key with (updlock, rowlock)

Can you help me?

I'm using Asp.net mvc 2, Sharp Architecture (with fluent automapping)

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i've found it.
i need to change the PrimaryKeyConvention of Fluent and set to native.

```
 public class PrimaryKeyConvention : IIdConvention
{
    public void Apply(FluentNHibernate.Conventions.Instances.IIdentityInstance instance)
    {
        instance.Column("Id");
        instance.UnsavedValue("0");
        //instance.GeneratedBy.HiLo("1000");
        instance.GeneratedBy.Native();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Had the same problem and your post helped me.

Comment: Of course using native generators (sql auto increment) is not recommended method.